# When is the cotangent bundle of a smooth manifold homogeneous?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, group-actions

I am interested in Hamiltonian systems defined on manifolds which are the cotangent bundle $T^*M$ of a homogeneous manifold $M$.

Thus, I would like to find some reference in which it is studied when, starting from a homogeneous $G-$manifold $M$, we can generate a transitive group action even on $T^*M$ (I don't mean by cotangent-lifting it, since it is quite rare to lift it to a transitive action).

For the tangent bundle, I have studied (for example here [Tangent bundle of homogeneous manifold](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1972-035-02/S0002-9939-1972-0310808-1/S0002-9939-1972-0310808-1.pdf)) that if the action of $G$ on $M$ is transitive and, for any $g\in G$, the action of $g$ defines a submersion, then we can induce a transitive action on $TM$ by means of the Lie group $\bar{G}=G\ltimes \mathfrak{g}$. I started working on similar reasoning with $\bar{G}=G\ltimes \mathfrak{g}^*$, but for the moment it is not clear to me.

I believe that we should add the assumption that the action is free, in order to hope to define a similar action on $T^*M$.

Are there some known results for $T^*M$?

Another possible interesting perspective on this problem would be: when is the dual of a homogeneous manifold, homogeneous too? This would include more possible cases, but it would be really interesting for me.

Comment: Since $TM$ and $T^\ast M$ are diffeomorphic (bundle isomorphic, even), you can use this to transport the transitive action on $TM$ to $T^\ast M$.  Is there some issue with this transitive action?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I did not think ti that approach to define the action. So, would you define the action as a composition between the one on $TM$ and the pull-back of such a diffeomorphism?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  (and more characters)